# Error when using pandas dataframe map function in ipython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm just starting out with Python and getting stuck on something while playing with the Kaggle Titanic data. 
https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

Here's what I am typing in an ipython notebook (train.csv comes from the titanic data from the kaggle link above):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/fakepath/titanic/data/train.csv")
```

I then continue with this to check if there's any bad data in the 'Sex' column:

```
df['Sex'].value_counts()
```

Which returns:

```
male      577

female    314

dtype: int64
```

```
df['Gender'] = df['Sex'].map( {'male': 1, 'female': 0} ).astype(int)
```

this doesn't produce any errors. To verify that it created a new column called 'Gender' with integer values :

```
df
```

which returns:

```
#    PassengerId    Survived    Pclass  Name    Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Ticket  Fare    Cabin   Embarked    Gender
    0   1   0   3   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris male    22  1   0   A/5 21171   7.2500  NaN S   1
    1   2   1   1   Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...   female  38  1   0   PC 17599    71.2833 C85 C   0
    2   3   1   3   Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26  0   0   STON/O2. 3101282    7.9250  NaN S   0
    3   4   1   1   Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)    female  35  1   0   113803  53.1000 C123    S   0
```

...success, the Gender column is appended to the end and is 0 for female, 1 for male. Now, I create a new pandas dataframe which is a subset of the df dataframe.

```
df2 = df[ ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Embarked'] ]
df2
```

which returns:

```
    Survived    Pclass  Age Gender  Embarked
0   0   3   22  1   S
1   1   1   38  0   C
2   1   3   26  0   S
3   1   1   35  0   S
4   0   3   35  1   S
5   0   3   NaN 1   Q
```

```
df2['Embarked'].value_counts()
```

...shows that there are 3 unique values (S, C, Q):

```
S    644
C    168
Q     77
dtype: int64
```

However, when I try to execute what I think is the same type of operation as when I converted male/female to 1/0, I get an error:

```
df2['Embarked_int'] = df2['Embarked'].map( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2}).astype(int)
```

returns:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-294c08f2fc80> in <module>()
----> 1 df2['Embarked_int'] = df2['Embarked'].map( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2}).astype(int)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error)
   2212 
   2213         mgr = self._data.astype(
-> 2214             dtype=dtype, copy=copy, raise_on_error=raise_on_error)
   2215         return self._constructor(mgr).__finalize__(self)
   2216 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
   2500 
   2501     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
-> 2502         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
   2503 
   2504     def convert(self, **kwargs):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, **kwargs)
   2455                                                  copy=align_copy)
   2456 
-> 2457             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
   2458 
   2459             if isinstance(applied, list):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error, values)
    369     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, raise_on_error=True, values=None):
    370         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, raise_on_error=raise_on_error,
--> 371                             values=values)
    372 
    373     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, raise_on_error=True, values=None,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in _astype(self, dtype, copy, raise_on_error, values, klass)
    399             if values is None:
    400                 # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 401                 values = com._astype_nansafe(self.values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    402                 values = values.reshape(self.values.shape)
    403             newb = make_block(values,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in _astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy)
   2616 
   2617         if np.isnan(arr).any():
-> 2618             raise ValueError('Cannot convert NA to integer')
   2619     elif arr.dtype == np.object_ and np.issubdtype(dtype.type, np.integer):
   2620         # work around NumPy brokenness, #1987

ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

Any idea why I get this error on the 2nd use of the map function but not the first? There are no NAN values in the Embarked column per value_counts(). I'm guessing it's a noob problem :)

Comment: I don't think you need those ``astype(int)``s, BTW.

Comment: Something doesn't add up you have 891 rows for your gender `value_counts` but 889 for your embarked, this means you must have `NaN` values, the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts) state that `NaN` value are not counted you can confirm this if you try `df['Embarked'].value_counts(dropna=False)`, this means you need to handle the NaN by filling them first before calling map

Comment: The last line of the error message: ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer  . You probably have to drop the NAs from your dataframe.

Comment: Regarding the redundant .astype(int), I thought it was strange that it was there. Copied that from the tutorial on Kaggle. Thanks for clarifying! @Ami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts) does not count `NaN` values, you can change this by doing `df['Embarked'].value_counts(dropna=False)` .

I looked at your `value_counts` for Gender column (577 + 314 = 891) versus Embarked column (644 + 168 + 77 = 889) and they are different by 2 which means you must have 2 `NaN` values.

So you either drop them first (using `dropna`) or fill them with some desired value using `fillna`.

Also the `astype(int)` is redundant as you are mapping to an int anyway.

Comment: I was not aware that `value_counts()` dropped NaN values by default. added this command `df2=df2.dropna(subset=['Embarked'])` and that removed the NaN, however I get a different error now when trying to run the map command:  `
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: You get that warning because `df2` is a copy of your original df due to this line: `df2 = df[ ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Embarked'] ]` so you need to do your Embarked mapping before taking a copy

Comment: I don't get the same error when running `df['Embarked_int'] = df['Embarked'].map( {'S': 0, 'C': 1, 'Q': 2})` (Thanks). Why does iPython care if I run the command against a copy vs. the original? I would have assumed there are no linkages...

Comment: Thinking about this further, if I wanted to have a separate dataframe with different columns, I'd be better off just re-importing the data and associating with a new dataframe rather than making copies of a subset of the data.

Comment: The warning gets raised to warn you in case your intention is that your operation should be performed on the orig df. If you did this `df2=df[ ['Survived', 'Pclass', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Embarked'] ].copy()` then no warning is raised and you don't need to load the data in again.

Comment: Typically a non-modifying operation such as taking a slice returns a view, but if you now try to modify that view without using `.loc`,, `.ix` or `.iloc` then a warning will be raised as your intention may have been that you wanted your reference to modify the orig df

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem on the same dataset.  Removing 'astype.int' solved the whole problem.